# Wordpress EC2 Security Practices

Tags: login, security

I started working for a client about 3 months ago. They have wordpress running on EC2 instance and no security/monitoring at all. We have about 8 users and 3 active. Recently 2 users reported some images missing and then all of a sudden the Footer template was removed.

I added activity monitoring and see constant request of logins thankfully they all are failing. Strange how all the requests are actual usernames in our system. Not sure how they got the usernames

I'm thinking of implementing the following. I'm very busy and want to get at least one in now. Of all the times listed which one should be my #1 priority?

Scan application

Firewall; aws WAF

Alerts

Change login url

Change passwords

Implement strong passwords

Implement MFA

Anything I'm missing anything from the list?

Also what apps do you recommend for Firewall (AWS WAF?) and scan application?

Thanks

Comment: I know it's only a small part of the question, but third-party plugin recommendation is out of this stack's scope and won't be able to be answered here. Possibly the other parts of it, but it sounds very subjective, which may not get you a proper answer.

Comment: As YourManDan mentions realized very subjective and turns out after understanding wp security better, found simple answer. I just ended up using popular plugin; Wordfence. Solves a lot of my list